# How can I prevent background position from moving/collapsing?

Tags: html, css, header, background-image, division

I'm pretty new to this stuff but I am learning as I go and taking courses too but sometimes I hit a small roadblock like this one.

When the browser is at 100% the back images are great but as you minimized all the way to 25% the background image position collapses or "hides" and I'd like the images' background position center top to remain intact no matter minimize or maximize.

I've attached an example:

[image] 
It is zoomed out to 25%. You can visit 
[medshopandbeyond.com](http://medshopandbeyond.com) and zoom out to also see the problem.

This is the html I used for the background images:

```
<div id="header-image6"></div>
```

This is the CSS I used for them

```
#header-image6 {
    background-image:url("{{ 'WhoWeAre3.jpg' | asset_url }}"); 
    height: 750px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:cover;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checked out your code and found this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
#header-image6{
    background-image:url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0930/6704/t/2/assets/WhoWeAre3.jpg?7803954532461737215");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:340px;
    height:250px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden
    }
}
```

For viewport width between 320px and 480px, you are re-setting the element's width and height and thus the image shrinks.

You can let the width and height to be 100% as it is in the default case. Please comment if there is anything else to put forward.

Comment: That makes sense in a way but how can it affect the desktop version. The rule I've set in the case you are talking about is for mobile online.

Comment: As you said, "as you minimized all the way to 25% the background image position collapses or "hides""... so you are reducing the width of the viewport and it will affect the desktop version as well.
Did you try removing the width and height as mentioned in the above case?

Comment: Hi! yes I did. I removed it. I changed it. And it still remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

In the class `"#header-image6"` that you provided, do change `"background-size:contain"`.

Hope so it will help you else do not hesitate to ask here.

Comment: So far I have tried that and it didn't work. I have tried max-width 100%, max-height 100%, min-width, min-height, background-size:contain, background-size: 100% 100% even setting the position to absolute with a z-index and  nothing, and a couple other things. All have not worked

Comment: Basically. background-size:contain works to a certain extent. but now the image is no longer full width from one side of the screen to another